# Can I use a 120 volt 50/60 Hz. tool on a 230 volt 50 Hz. circuit?

Tags: electrical, powertools

I want to get the [Dewalt DW660 cut out tool](http://www.dewalt.com/tools/fastening-cut-out-tools-dw660.aspx), it has been made for the north american market so it runs on 120 volts. It has the following specs:

> 120V ~ 50/60 Hz
>   5 Amps
>   600 Watts

The voltage where I live is a 230V/50 Hz. Would it run with no issues or overheating if I use a proper step down transformer? I am planning on buying one with a max 1000 Watt power as I've read some threads that indicated that it should be at least 1.5 times the wattage of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with a step down transformer since the output should be 120~10 (120 with 10 +/- possible) with a low quality transformer, which, apparently the tool can handle. In a good transformer it should be 120~2. So the output wont be much different than regular 120 volt output. If it also increases the frequency, that would be much better. And make sure the continuous max rating is 700~20 volts. Otherwise you have a small danger of the lifetime of the transformer decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why you wouldn't just buy the right voltage in the first place. At a glance, Makita makes a similar tool; I'm sure there are others.

That said, if you plan on other wrong voltage tools in the future, I'd overdo it as much as possible on the transformer. You'll get longer on/off cycles and more flexibility in general. Check the specs on whatever you buy to ensure that the available current isn't just the initial peak.

Comment: The reasons are: I was looking for something that would mount easily on my CNC machine. It should have a cord since it will run for many hours a day. The price should be reasonable and should be powerful enough to finish jobs quickly. Variable speed is irrelevant and it should have good reviews from other CNC users.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to pay far more for a step down transformer than you would for two copies of the same tool for different regions.

Can you use a 60Hz AC motor at 50Hz? Probably, it will spin/oscillate 17% slower which might cause issues but that is unlikely.

The same line of AC motor are very often made in 115V and 230V models just with different windings. I would strongly recommend not trying to use a step down transformer when the much better option of getting the right tool is cheaper and easier.

Comment: I thought that "120V ~ 50/60 Hz" means it will work fine on both frequencies. Isnt that the case?

Comment: This tool almost certainly uses a brushed universal motor, which doesn't care about frequency. Plus, as OP noted, it specifically says it is compatible with 50Hz.